# How to add comma instead of dot after last author in reference?

Tags: bibliographies, punctuation

Please suggest how to replace dot(.) after the last author in reference as shown in Figure.

The code used in premeble is:

```
\documentclass[AMA,Times1COL]{WileyNJDv5} 
        %STIX1COL,STIX2COL,STIXSMALL
         \articletype{Article}%

       \received{Date Month Year}
        \revised{Date Month Year}
       \accepted{Date Month Year}
      \journal{Journal}
       \volume{00}
        \copyyear{2023}
         \startpage{1}

        \raggedbottom
  \begin{document}
    Main text................
    ...................
  \bibliography{wileyNJD-AMA}
    \end{document}
```

[image: highlighted dot that I want to replace with the comma]

I have references in separate files (wileyNJD-AMA.bib)and their structure is like this:

```
    @article{Mood,
   author ="Sharifi-Mood, Nima and Liu, Iris B. and Stebe, Kathleen 
    J.",
        title  ="Curvature capillary migration of microspheres",
       journal  ="Soft Matter",
       year  ="2015",
       volume  ="11",
    issue  ="34",
      pages  ="6768-6779",
        publisher  ="The Royal Society of Chemistry",
      doi  ="10.1039/C5SM00310E",
     url  ="http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C5SM00310E",
       }
```

Comment: why did you tag that with hyperref??

Comment: Thanks@Ulrike Fischer
, I have removed hyperref, However, could you suggest any solution?

Comment: no you don't provide a complete example that can be used for a test.  It is completely unclear what you are doing to create the bibliography and if the style can be adjusted.

Comment: @Fischer, I have updated the question by adding some more info.

Comment: Apparently Wiley wants a period in that position. Why would you change the house style?

Comment: Editor said we have to put comma instead of period.